# No constructor found while instantiating Assembly on runtime

Tags: c#, dll, system.reflection

After loading a DLL and obtaining a type, I get an exception trying to instantiate it:

```
Assembly dll = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\path\file.dll");
Type type = dll.GetType("namespace.CustomClass");
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type); // <-- System.MissingMethodException
```

> "No constructor with 0 parameters defined for this object" (average translation)

Exploring the loaded type, I can see the `DeclaredConstrunctors` -> `{Void .ctor()}`

But calling `type.GetConstructors()` I get an empty array (I guess that means that only default constructor exists?)

I neither found any factory class that returns an object of my class, or an `getInstance` function.

Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: What is `namespace.CustomClass`?

Comment: Also, `type.GetConstructors()` only gets public constructors.

Comment: it's the FullName of the type, there exists a class, and an Instance with same name but without the "class" postfix.

Comment: Yeah, I gathered as much. What's the definition of the class? Do you have access to that? In particular, is it a Singleton? Does it have private constructors? (I'm guessing that that's the problem).

Comment: I only have access to the metadata. It appears as "public class" with some interfaces, and a few "public virtual" functions. But nothing that can return an object of the same Class. No private constructor neither.

Comment: So, what's the metadata on the constructor you saw?

Comment: There is no constructor declared at all. But this dll is being used in another application, so I have to assume that it is well coded.

Comment: *But this dll is being used in another application, so I have to assume that it is well coded.* Why do you have to assume that?

Comment: Also, looking at `DeclaredConstructor`, what information does it show about the constructor?

Comment: There is a {Void .ctor()}. IsPublic and IsPrivate are both `false` (not nice). IsAssembly and IsConstructor are `true`.

Comment: Maybe internal?

Comment: Nothing... I'll try to find a different approach. Thank you

Comment: I tried with an internal constructor - it looked like IsPublic and IsPrivate were both false for me. That's a possibility as well. BTW - any parameters?

Comment: No parameters, and no idea how to reach the internal constructor :-/

Comment: I've found an ocx with the same name in another folder. I'll check if I have something to do with it.

Comment: @EJoshuaS finally I found how to instantiate the class by registering a related OCX. Maybe the DLL was only for interface proposes

Comment: Seems plausible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DLL had a related OCX file placed in another folder.

The file has been registered using:

> Regsvr32 .\file.ocx

After that, I've been able to instantiate an object calling:

> using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
>
> MyAssemblyName object = (MyAssemblyName) Interaction.CreateObject( "MyNamespace.MyAssemblyName", "");

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities here.

The first is that the all of the defined parameters take parameters. There's no guarantee that every class has a 0-parameter constructor. Here's an example of some code that produces this error:

```
public class SomeCons
{
    public SomeCons(string cons)
    {

    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    object result = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(SomeCons));
}
```

The second possibility `namespace.CustomClass` has a private constructor. The following code produces similar behavior to what you saw. I also included an example of how to find the actual constructor - you want to [use Binding Flags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
private class NoCons
{
    private NoCons()
    {

    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // As you saw, this shows one declared constructor
    Type exploratory = typeof(NoCons);

    // Returns nothing
    ConstructorInfo[] constructors = typeof(NoCons).GetConstructors();

    // Returns 1 constructor
    constructors = typeof(NoCons).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
}
```

Please note that it may be important to understand exactly *why* `namespace.CustomClass` has a private constructor in the first place. That's actually a really common thing to do if you're trying to define a Singleton, in which case you probably don't want to call the constructor directly.

For a singleton like this:

```
private class NoCons
{
    private NoCons()
    {

    }

    private static NoCons _instance;

    public static NoCons Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new NoCons();
            }

            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
```

try something like this:

```
Type exploratory = typeof(NoCons);

PropertyInfo singletonProperty = exploratory.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).FirstOrDefault(prop => prop.Name.Contains("Instance"));

string name = singletonProperty.GetGetMethod().Name;

var noCons = exploratory.GetMethod(name).Invoke(null, null) as NoCons;
```

Comment: @MarioM. Could be some variant of that - you might want to try looking at all of the public static properties to see if one of them looks like a singleton instance.

Comment: No static properties to store an instance